# How do I insure I am setting up the grid system properly in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout, grid-layout

I have just started using Bootstrap (I have never used a grid system before) and am having a problem understanding the proper way of implementing the fluid grid system. I am a little worried that I may have to redesign the site. Please see the image for more detail.

**Problem 1:** What is the proper way of adding a white border/padding around the entire site and still get it to scale. Do I have to add it the the start and end of each new row or is there an easier way to apply it globally?

**Problem 2:**  Some of my content, such as the controls to the picture slider, land in the margins. Will this be a problem or is it simply solved by creating a span that contains every column with some padding?

**Problem 3:** I know Bootstrap has a default 12 column system but it looks like you can customize it pretty easy with  he "custom download". Is it  as simple as entering 14 into the @gridColumns field or will I also need to change the px widths as well ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1:** one option is to have a div wrap your content, for example:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        // ...
    </div>        
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
    border-right: 4px solid #fff;
    border-left: 4px solid #fff;
}
```

**Problem 2:**  You can use something like `margin-left: -20px` for example to push the item out of the container.

**Problem 3:**  Yes, you can customize using the builder, but if, for example, you want to keep the default 940px width, but have 14 columns, you will have to adjust the column width variables as well.